# Right click menu disappears after restarting the browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. I have added a new menu item in the right click menu for the extension. It works fine after installed.Then when I restart the browser, the new right click menu item disappears!But the extension work well, only the new menu item is gone! 
I have compared the chrome official sample for contextMenu, seems the same. I just put the create menu code in chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {}) like the sample does.....
Any idea why this happens?

Many thanks!

updated:
Add the property in the manifest file:
    "background": {
    **"persistent": false,**
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest moving the code to a separate function and then calling that function from both `onInstalled` and `chrome.runtime.onStartup`. The first one is invoked when you install or update, while the second one is when you reopen the browser.

Comment: I found the reason. I missed a prpperty in the manifest file:"persistent": false, If I add this, the onInstalled event will execute every time when the browser startup. Thanks for your reply!