# Moving code to a separate function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm working on a Google Chrome Extension.

I have the same problem like this: [Right click menu disappears after restarting the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480457/right-click-menu-disappears-after-restarting-the-browser)

The solution is to use:

**chrome.runtime.onInstalled**.addListener(function() {
**chrome.runtime.onStartup**.addListener(function() {

I've tested it and it works, but now I have duplicate code:

```
//context menu
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: '1',
    id: 'a',
    contexts: ['all'],
});
});
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: '1',
    id: 'a',
    contexts: ['all'],
});
});
```

How can I shorten the code? Im really new to JavaScript and would be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function that creates the context menus separately, then pass that function in as the argument to `addListener`:

```
function createContextMenu() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: '1',
    id: 'a',
    contexts: ['all']
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(createContextMenu);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(createContextMenu);
```